# What would cause my html5 form to validate on page load?

Tags: html, validation, pseudo-class

The title pretty much asks the question. I have a form that is empty when it opens. There is an input on it that has the `required` attribute. However for some reason HTML is applying the `:invalid` pseudoclass to this empty input before the user touches the field. Can anyone name some reasons why that might be happening? I put breakpoints into my validation functions and none of them are executed at load time.

Before anyone asks, it isn't really possible to post code for this. I'm really just looking for a few possible reasons to get started with debugging it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The HTML `required` attribute in the `<input>` tag specifies that an input field must be filled in before submitting the form. Removing this attribute should solve your problem. I think HTML mark-up is rather permissive there shouldn't be much debugging to it. 
It's preferrable to use a validation service such as the [W3C Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: I don't want to remove the required tag - I just don't want it to validate before it submits. I believe this behavior is in the spec, and I may have a bug that is causing it to validate early...

Comment: Maybe if you post your code then? This seems to me like standard html behaviour. There probably isn't a workaround for it. Unless it's your listing.

Comment: What on Earth does HTML markup validation have to do with form validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use novalidate, but it does not stop the :invalid pseudoclass from being added. I removed the required attribute and handle all validation with js.